# Dual Honda systems

Tags: abelian-varieties, deformation-theory

Hello,

There is an equivalence of categories between p-divisible groups over the ring of Witt vectors $W(k)$ and the category of "Honda systems", that is couples $(M,L)$ formed by a Dieudonné module $M$ over $k$ and a submodule $L\subset M$ such that
$$\frac{L}{pL}=\frac{M}{FM}$$

I would like to know if there is is a notion of "dual Honda system", and if it corresponds to the dual p-divisible group through the equivalence above.

Thank you !

JSK